# Make scripts readable for any ssh user charset (utf8,latin1,...)

Tags: bash, character-encoding

I am writing bash scripts that will be executed by remote users by ssh session.
My problem is : the users terminals (linux console, windows putty, ...) are either using UTF-8 charset or ISO88591/ISO885915. I can know what charset they use through the $LANG variable.
Is there a good and easy way to make my scripts having the correct output regardless the client charset ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Example of the output? or script fragment? Scripts typically are using other commands to accomplish bigger goals. As such it is likely to depend on the other commands (and their output), not the shell or script itself.

Comment: Exemple of script (encoded in UTF8) :
#!/bin/bash
echo "L'action a été effectuée"

Executed by a client whith ISO88591 charset, i get :
L'action a Ã©tÃ© effectuÃ©e

And if I encode the script with iso88591, clients using utf8 will have : L'action a �t� effectu�e

Comment: I have multiples scripts that can call each other, that why i'm looking for a global solution instead of adding a function to each script in order to convert each "echo" or "printf" command with iconv according to the $LANG variable.